# What is the value of a sum similar to Basel problem but with fibonacci coefficient

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers, cesaro-summable

The title is pretty self-explanatory. What is the value of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{f_n}{n^2}$

Answer (score 2):

$f_n$ grows exponentially, so the sum diverges. To elaborate, if $a_n := \dfrac{f_n}{n^2}$, it can be shown that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| = \varphi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} > 1,$$ and so by the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test), the series diverges.